# How do you send custom attributes to AWS Cognito from Amplify Authentication UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I want to send custom attributes to AWS cognito using amplify. When I send all other attributes (username, email, name) it works as expected.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Amplify} from 'aws-amplify';
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import awsExports from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsExports);


const formFields = {
  signUp: {
    company_name: {
      placeholder: 'Please enter a company name',
      key: 'custom:company_name',
      isRequired: true,
      label: 'Company Name:'
    },
  },
}

export default function App() {

  return (
    <Authenticator formFields={formFields}>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user && user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

Above is my react code. Below is a lambda event that runs when to user signs up.

```
{'version': '1', 'region': 'eu-west-1', 'userPoolId': 'eu-west-1_********', 'userName': '****************', 'callerContext': {'awsSdkVersion': 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown', 'clientId': '*******************'}, 'triggerSource': 'PreSignUp_SignUp', 'request': {'userAttributes': {'name': 'Ben Dover', 'email': 'bdover@hotmail.co.uk'}, 'validationData': None}, 'response': {'autoConfirmUser': False, 'autoVerifyEmail': False, 'autoVerifyPhone': False}}
```

So can I get the company_name into the event.
[This is my cognito](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjVFs.png)